# AWS Lambda with Zappa fails on "import module 'handler': No module named 'werkzeug' "

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

After deploying my python application with Zappa and visiting the aws link, I can see the following error:

[image]

When I checked the logs, I found the source of the error:

[image]

I then decided to `pip install -r requirements.txt` to ensure that it's installed inside my virtual environment (which it is):

```
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug==0.12 in ./flaskapi/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 41))
```

Something is going wrong when it's uploaded to AWS. I'm not sure if this is the core issue, but I did notice the package name in the logs is different than the one inside `requirements.txt` file. The package name in the logs doesn't start with a capitalized 'W', while the package name in the `requirements.txt` does. Other than that, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: are you using a virtual environment? I wonder if calling your virtual environment folder `env` would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by upgrading to python 3.7 . I would recommend starting a new virtualenv, configured to use python 3.7 .

if you do not have python3.7 on your system, you will need to install it. This site is the one I used. Works on AWS cloud9 too.

[installing python 3.7](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/)

`virtualenv env -p python3.7`
`source ./env/bin/activate`
`python --version`
output should be "Python 3.7.X"

then continue setting up your app like normal.